# ¿Es común el uso de "birlar" con el significado de "matar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, palabras-raras

En el DLE aparece [**birlar**](https://dle.rae.es/birlar?) con varias acepciones, entre las que me llama la atención la tercera:

> 3. tr. coloq. **Matar o derribar a alguien de un golpe o un disparo.**

No conocía esta acepción y me ha sorprendido mucho. ¿Se usa con frecuencia?

Comment: No lo escuché en ninguna variante del español. Si es coloquial, les faltó aclarar en dónde se dice eso. Si se usa en algún lado, probablemente sea en España (por el sesgo del DLE) pero no estoy seguro. Sea como fuere, si lo decís con ese sentido, en general lo más probable es que no te entiendan nada. BTW, yo la única acepción que conocía es la de *tirar por segunda vez en el juego de bolos*

Comment: @tac: aparece ya en el Diccionario de Autoridades (1726): BIRLAR. Dícese tambien assi quando con escopéta, ballesta, ù otro instrumento se mata, ù derriba à alguno de un golpe: y assi se suele decir à Fuláno le birlaron, esto es le derribaron muerto de algun golpe.

Comment: Nunca escuché esa acepción. Para mí: o es un uso histórico/antiguo y hasta poético si se quiere, o bien se restringe a alguna región reducida. Muchas palabras o acepciones que están en ese diccionario nunca salieron del ámbito literario, por ejemplo ‘ranzón’. Por eso, lo único que digo es: cuidado.